PopScope doesn't work for flutter web. it pops the screen even after setting it to false
Iam building an flutter web app and I have implemented PageView in my signin page where it has got total 3 pages in pageview . SO I am trying to reduce the page view index if the page index is not 0.  i want to pop the screen when the page reaches 0. But it doesn't work as expected . Below is the code . If anyone can look into let me know if i am doing any mistake.
PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        LoggingService.info(didPop);
        if (context.read<AuthBloc>().state.signinPageVeiwIndex != 0) {
          context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthEvent.changeSigninPageIndex(
                index: context.read<AuthBloc>().state.signinPageVeiwIndex - 1,
              ));
        }
        else {
          AutoRouter.of(context).maybePop();
        }
      },

